# Creating a copy of a large database

Tags: sql-server

I want to make a copy of a largish SQL 2008 database (1TB). I only have 1.9TB of disk space free so I don't have enough to create a backup of the database and restore it into another.

Are there any other techniques I can use? How to I do it quickly as possible?

Is it ok to just make a copy of the MDF, LDF and NDF files - rename them and then just attach the database?

Comment: If you db size is 1TB and you have 1.9 TB free, why can't you create a copy on the same server.

Comment: You have normal backups, right?

Comment: @Ash that is what I am asking, "Is it ok to just make a copy of the MDF, LDF and NDF files"?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can detach, copy the .ldf, mdf and .ndf files to another location and attach them.

Are you using backup compression?

> Beginning in SQL Server 2008 R2,
>   backup compression is supported by SQL
>   Server 2008 R2 Standard and all higher
>   editions. Every edition of SQL Server
>   2008 and later can restore a
>   compressed backup.

Comment: Thanks mitch, unfortunately we're not using R2.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool such as VS2010 Premium or SqlDelta that supports schema and data comparison and migration. I've used it to create a complete copy of database, when I haven't had possibilities to make and access a disk based backup.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if you're saying "I don't have backups" but...

As a workaround:

- Plug in an external 2TB backup drive for temporary backup space
- Restore to a compressed folder: this will run like a dog though

Notes:

- Do you not separate data, log and backups onto different volumes?
- How do you manage normal backups?
- Is the backup 1TB (eg 1TB data) or is the DB 1TB on disk?

Comment: I don't have a back up. And I dont have enough space to store a back up and the copy of the database. Data and logs are on separate volumes.

Comment: @Dan: is this production?

Comment: No its not production.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can just use the database copy wizard.  Just use the same server for the source and destination.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188664.aspx